# RubyMine - too short escape sequence (ArgumentError)

Tags: cucumber, rubymine

In rubymine 4.5.3, I try to run a scenario:

```
Scenario: I want to buy icecream, then watch a movie
  Given I am at a mall
  When I buy icecream
  Then I should be allowed to watch a movie
```

The scenario contains a comma, so when I right-click and hit play, the Element Name Filter looks like this:

```
I want to buy icecream\, then watch a movie
```

But then I get this stack trace:

```
too short escape sequence (ArgumentError)
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb:194:in `block (2 levels) in parse!'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1360:in `call'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1360:in `block in parse_in_order'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1347:in `catch'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1347:in `parse_in_order'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1341:in `order!'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1432:in `permute!'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1453:in `parse!'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb:119:in `parse!'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:25:in `parse!'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:55:in `configuration'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:63:in `run_drb_client'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
C:/ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

To fix the issue I change the Element Name Filter, and remove the backslash:

```
I want to buy icecream, then watch a movie
```

Now the scenario runs correctly.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Just confirmed that the same issue occurs with double-quotes

EDIT: Confirmed the issue still exists in RubyMine 4.5.4

Comment: Created bug report:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-12116
Please vote it up!